# HIbernate 3 - сложный HQL запрос

Tags: hibernate, hql

Здравствуйте уважаемые!
У меня имеются 2 таблички в моей БД:
**Films

Distributors**

В табличке **Films** есть ссылка на табличку **Distributors: id_distributor**, в свою очередь в табличке **Distributors** есть поле **name**. Мне нужно создать запрос в Hibernate3 что бы выбиралась вся информация из таблички **Films**, но при этом вместо идентификатора **id_distributor**, выводился его **name**.

Помогите пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо.

Comment: join надо юзать :)

Comment: а по-конкретнее можно пожалуйста?

Comment: зачем для такого простого запроса hql?

Comment: У меня просто приложение использует Spring + Hibernate. Как-то по-другому не получается :(

Answer (score 2):

```
select f.*, d.name from films f left join distributors d on d.name = f.id_distributor
```

Comment: @Gorets автор просил в виде HQL запроса :)

Answer (score 1):

В классе:

```
@Column(name = "name_in_sql")
private boolean name;
```

или в запросе

```
"select f.*, d.name as name2 from films f left join distributors d on d.name = f.id_distributor"
```